# is evp encrypt sequential or stateful?

Tags: encryption, openssl, evp-cipher

I am trying to use the evp encryption and decryption libraries for encryption/ decryption of message data over tcp sockets. I first create the cipher context using `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()`, then init it using `EVP_EncryptInit_ex(newctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, crypkey, iv)` and then use the `EncryptUpdate` calls before sending data over socket.

Everything works fine if every `EncryptUpdate` call is followed by a socket `send` call. But if I try to encrypt and store something for sending later then I always get corrupted encrypted data.

Since I am totally new to this, I can't help but wonder if this is by design or am I missing something really simple here.

On further search, best i could find was that `gcm` mode maintains a counter on both encryption and decryption side as mentioned in the comment. Does this imply that `Encryptupdate` is state based at the very least?

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/what-is-the-difference-between-cbc-and-gcm-mode#comment3718_2311

Example code below. When I send `enpkt2`, the server receiver will reject it because it is expecting the packet that was encrypted first. Else the context on server and client sides would go out of sync. Am I wrong with the above understanding?

```
   EVP_CIPHER_CTX *enctx;

   enctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();    

    if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(enctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, crypkey, iv))
        printf("ENCRYPT init failed\n");    

unsigned char *pkt1, *enpkt1, *pkt2, *enpkt2;   

int ciplen1, ciplen2;

if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(enctx, enpkt1, &ciplen1, pkt1, pktlen1))
        printf("encrypt error\n");

if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(enctx, enpkt2, &ciplen2, pkt2, pktlen2))
        printf("encrypt error\n");

send(socket, enpkt2, ciplen2);
```

Comment: The state is maintained in the context object. Almost all crypt modes of operation, except ECB, are stateful. That's one reason why there is an EVP_EncryptFinal call that must be last one of the sequence. Finally, *sequential* and *serial* are generally considered synonyms in this context.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, thanks (corrected the title). From what I read, that was the likely conclusion. Being new to this, just wanted a confirmation. So there is no way I can keep multiple packets encrypted and decide last minute what to send across?

Comment: Of course you can, but you'd need to use your own buffer to hold the ciphertext (including the call to `EVP_EncryptFinal`). The cipher itself has only got a tiny buffer - usually a single block - and I'd argue it would be bad design even if it wouldn't (as that would be by chance).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, that confuses me all over again. So far if I call `evp_EncryptUpdate` on the same data twice, I see the encrypted packets are different. This leads me to believe that encryption is stateful. How can then I encrypt packet1 and then packet2 and still send packet2 first across? Wouldn't the state of decrypt context on server be out of sync with my encrypt context in such a case?

Comment: Yes, they are statefull. This is why you should not reuse the context for either encryption. If the key and IV (nonce) are identical for both contexts then the decryption would proceed as expected. If both packets are send then you will need a different way of setting the IV (nonce) the same way on both sides (e.g. by including a different, random IV with the message). Remember that these contexts are very lightweight; there is really no reason to keep them around. For the GCM cipher, the only thing you need is a key (which of course can be static) and an IV / nonce.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, if the decryption side is using the same context over n over again, then, my creating and using fresh context for every encryption won't work, right?

Comment: Not with GCM obviously as the authentication would fail. It can be made to work for other modes and even *theoretically* for GCM, but I would definitely keep encryption and decryption code largely symmetric on this front. For symmetric encryption / decryption you need symmetric code, news at eleven ;)